# How do I install gems in Rubymine?

Tags: rubygems, installation, rubymine

I can't seem to find how to add it in this settings view

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal/cmd/iterm you would simply write

```
gem install rake
```

Also you could create file called Gemfile that would have all the gems in

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rake'
gem 'sinatra'
```

and in the future any other gems you would need, Rubymine should be able to install those for you (even if you move your project to new machine that haven't installed them yet).